# How do you toggle credential manager persistence from login session to enterprise?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, session, credentials-manager

I have a situation where when domain users are logged in credential manager persistence is set to session, so when they try to cache their Outlook credentials, it only lasts the login session. If I use a local computer account, the persistence is set to Enterprise, and I can cache the credentials. That means to me it is either a login script, or a user side GPO. Or possibly I have combed through the GPOs and can not find any trace of a credential manager persistence setting. I also can't find any registry setting for this. I have googled the heck out of this for the past 2 hours.

Any ideas? The clients are all versions of Windows, 7, 8 and 10. The AD server is Server 2016. Outlook is current Office 365 deployment, but the issue is on all versions of Office from 2013 on.

*******************UPDATE**********************

I found that credential manager was setting the credential persistence to session login, which will not fully cache the credentials.

---

Comment: What version(s) of Windows, Office?

Comment: @music2myear added details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. The internal domain and the external third party email domain matched, which causes problems for credential manager's persistence value. I added the DNS shortname to the UPN in active Directory, and added this as the username suffix. Once I logged in with username@DNSshortname rather than username@domain.com, the credential manager was able to tag the persistence for the credential as Enterprise rather than Session Login.